# divide a table into sub_table by query using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a table (table1) with 3 column (ID,V,R), I want to divide it to some table based on ID. for example suppose it is a table1:

```
ID      V      R
1       1      T
1       2      F
2       1      T
2       3      T
3       4      F
```

then because I have 3 type of ID (which it could be more or less) I want 3 different table like this:
table1_1:

```
ID      V      R
1       1      T
1       2      F
```

table 1_2:

```
ID      V      R
2       1      T
2       3      T
```

table 1_3:

```
ID      V      R
3       4      F
```

is there any solution to do it in Laravel?
I apologize in advance if my question is so simple.

Comment: What is your need to separate them into different tables?

Comment: @thisiskelvin first of all table1 is so big and then the ID repeats alot so I want to separate table1 so I can just mention the ID of each sub_table once and show "V" and "R", and finally I need sub_table for another query.

Comment: Could we say that once the records have been split up, there would be no need for this `id` field (as we would need another `id` for each record, and it would be repeated with every record).

Comment: yes I just mentioned it for better understanding in my question but if the answer could just give me the 2 other columns (V R) I would be happy!